# How to compute this exponential matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
\begin{align}
[\omega] &= \begin{bmatrix}0 &-\omega_3 &\omega_2 \\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\ -\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \in so(3) \\
e^{[\omega]\theta} &= I + \sin\theta[\omega] + (1-\cos\theta)[\omega]^2 \\
e^{[\mathcal{S}]\theta} &= \begin{bmatrix} e^{[\omega]\theta} & (I\theta + (1-\cos\theta)[\omega]+(\theta-\sin\theta)[\omega]^2)v \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad v\in \mathbb{R}^3
\end{align}
$$
In the book I'm reading, the authors define the following formula,
$$
e^{[\mathcal{B}]\theta} = e^{M^{-1}[\mathcal{S}]M\theta}, \quad \quad M \in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}
$$
The matrix $M$ is given. How can I compute $e^{[\mathcal{B}]\theta}$ using the equations at the top?

Comment: You say the matrix $M$ "is given," but you haven't shared it with us Readers.  Nonetheless the idea is that with a similarity transformation in hand, the power series expansion for $e^{[\mathcal B]\theta}$ is similar to the corresponding power series expansion for $e^{[S]\theta}$.

Comment: @hardmath M contains real numbers. Not sure if you need the actual values but I can provide it.

Comment: What is $so(3)$ supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is indeed to compute $M^{-1}e^{[S]\theta}M$. The reasoning is as follows. Recall that the exponential map of matrices is defined by its power series:
$$e^A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^n. $$

Note that for all $n$, $$(M^{-1}AM)^n = M^{-1}AM \cdot M^{-1}AM \cdot ... \cdot M^{-1}AM = M^{-1} A^n, M$$
which implies $$e^{M^{-1}AM} = M^{-1} e^A M. $$
Apply this with $A = \theta [S]$ to see that you need to compute $M^{-1}e^{[S]\theta}M$ to find $e^{M^{-1} [S]\theta M}$.